# Find duplicate keys in Two Arrays of Dictionaries to update old Array dictionary with new Array dictionary

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to update a saved dictionary with a new dictionary. New values need to be appended to the dictionary if no value exists. Also update old existing value with new value for a dictionary.

old saved array of dictionaries I have:

```
 var savedDict = [
             ["id":"1","pic":"Alice.png","name":"Alice Smith","position":"Nurse"],
             ["id":"2","pic":"brad.png","name":"Brad Smith MD","position":"Primary Doctor"],
             ["id":"12","pic":"bob.png","name":"Bob Smith PhD","position":"Hospital Coordinator"],
            ]
```

new download Array of dictionaries:

```
let newDict =   [
             ["id":"1","pic":"alice.png","name":"Alice Smith","position":"Nurse"],
             ["id":"2","pic":"brad.png","name":"Brad Smith MD","position":"Primary Doctor"],
             ["id":"3","pic":"user.png","name":"Dr. Quam","position":"Immunologist"],
             ["id":"4","pic":"jennifer.jpg","name":"Jennifer Johnson","position":"Case Manager"],
             ["id":"5","pic":"user.png","name":"John Banks MD","position":"Cardiologist"],
             ["id":"6","pic":"tammie.png","name":"Tammie Summers","position":"Case Manager"]
            ]
```

I want to:
1.update "Alice.png" to "alice.png" for "id" = 1,
2.ignore "id" = 2 because same for both Array of dicts,
3. append all the new items from newDict into savedDict

final dict should be:

```
 upToDateDict = [
             ["id":"1","pic":"alice.png","name":"Alice Smith","position":"Nurse"],
             ["id":"2","pic":"brad.png","name":"Brad Smith MD","position":"Primary Doctor"],
             ["id":"12","pic":"bob.png","name":"Bob Smith PhD","position":"Hospital Coordinator"],
             ["id":"3","pic":"user.png","name":"Dr. Quam","position":"Immunologist"],
             ["id":"4","pic":"jennifer.jpg","name":"Jennifer Johnson","position":"Case Manager"],
             ["id":"5","pic":"user.png","name":"John Banks MD","position":"Cardiologist"],
             ["id":"6","pic":"tammie.png","name":"Tammie Summers","position":"Case Manager"]
            ]
```

I tried this so far:

```
 import UIKit
 import Foundation

 func arrayContains(array:[[String:String]], value:[String:String]) -> Bool {
     for item in array {
         if item == value {
             return true
         }
     }
     return false
 }

 var upToDateDict = savedDict//Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()

 //Save all of the dictionaries from the 1st array (savedDict) that aren't in the 2nd array (newDict)
 for item in newDict {
     if !arrayContains(array: savedDict, value: item) {
         upToDateDict.append(item)
     }
 }

 print(upToDateDict)

 //find duplicate keys and check if need to update saved dict with new dict

 let key = "id"

 for dict1 in savedDict {
     if let value = dict1[key] {
         for dict2 in newDict {
             if dict2[key] == value { //if true duplicate "id" key's  found

                 if dict1 != dict2 { //not duplicate for all keys, so update saved with new dictionary

                     print("found \(key):\(value) in both arrays")
                     print("dict1:\(dict1)")
                     print("dict2:\(dict2)")

                     savedDict[dict1] = dict2 //what I want to do but will not build 

                 } else {}//all keys duplicate in dict1 and dict2

             }
         }
     }
 }
```

I just want to overwrite this dictionary with new so I update ["id":"1","pic":"Alice.png"... to ["id":"1","pic":"alice.png"... but this is not working:

```
 savedDict[dict1] = dict2
```

Comment: you should create custom `Class` instead of dictionaries like this. After that everything would be much easier.

Comment: What would the custom class look like?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should create

```
class Employee {
    var id: String
    var pic: String
    var name: String
    var position: String

    init(id: String, pic: String, name: String, position: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.pic = pic
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
    }
}
```

then you will have

```
var oldEmployes: [Employee] = [Employee(id: "1", pic: "pic.png", name: "Name", position: "Position"), 
                               Employee(id: "2", pic: "pic2.png", name: "Name2", position: "Position2")]
var newEmployes: [Employee] = [Employee(id: "2", pic: "pic21.png", name: "Name21", position: "Position2"), 
                               Employee(id: "3", pic: "pic3.png", name: "Name3", position: "Position3")]
```

to update array do something like (can be much more presentable using high level functions, but I think this way it looks clear)

```
for employee in newEmployes {
     var isNew = true
     for oldEmployee in oldEmployes {
           if oldEmployee.id == employee.id {
               oldEmployee.name = employee.name
               oldEmployee.pic = employee.pic
               oldEmployee.position = employee.position
               isNew = false
           }
     }
     if isNew {
         oldEmployes.append(employee)
     }
}
```

Comment: you should conform the `Employee` to a compere protocol, then it is more easy to compare employee instances or put them in arrays

Comment: and be carefull if you decide to change the `class` to a `struct` because then you can not just update the `oldEmployee` object - because `struct` is handled by value and not by reference

Comment: Thanks this looks good. Can you show me an example of how to initialize oldEmployes with data above.

Comment: the protocol is named `Equatable` i mention in my first comment ( https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable )

Comment: @Brian: look at the `init(id: String, pic: String, name: String, position: String)` where you can `let emp1 = Employee(id: "1", pic: "abc.jpg", name: "def", position: "efg")`

Comment: @Brian edited. @muescha used to use `contains(where: {$0.id == testObject.id})` , will try to refactor with this protocol. looks amazing.

Comment: you can add also a different solution to the problem of updating/appending since the update dictionary has the full employee data: 1) `filter` the oldEmployes and return only employees which are not in newEmployes  2) just append then the newEmployes array to the oldEmployes array

Comment: the other solution is to have an dictionary with the id as the key. then just update or append depending on the key is avaiable or not